# NSManagedObjectContext Async/Await perform(schedule:_:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, async-await, xcode13.2

I'm working on an App that still supports iOS 13 and need to fetch some data with CoreData.

This is how I would normally do it

```
context.perform({
  let results = try context.fetch(request)
})
```

Now with Xcode 13 and async/await being available back to iOS 13 I get a compiler error

> 'perform(schedule:_:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer

Jumping to definition shows the following new API in CoreData

```
@available(macOS 12.0, iOS 15.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
extension NSManagedObjectContext {

    public func performAndWait<T>(_ block: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T

    public func perform<T>(schedule: NSManagedObjectContext.ScheduledTaskType = .immediate, _ block: @escaping () throws -> T) async rethrows -> T
}
```

When commenting out the code in the Block, it instead jumps to the old API in CoreData/NSManagedObjectContext

```
/* asynchronously performs the block on the context's queue.  Encapsulates an autorelease pool and a call to processPendingChanges */
@available(iOS 5.0, *)
open func perform(_ block: @escaping () -> Void)
```

Why does the compiler select the new variant of `perform` and how can I force it to use the older non-async version?

Edit: Here is a minimal sample project that demonstrates the issue: https://github.com/iv-mexx/CoreDataRepro

Comment: Available async/await feature, not methods implemented in the future SDK's. If you want you can implement your's own async perform method

Comment: I've tried this and I can't reproduce the error, even in an `async` function. Can you edit the question to add more detail about where this code appears? It's probably very relevant to the problem you're having.

Comment: @TomHarrington I've edited the question and added a link to a new sample project that replicates the issue.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I want to use the old non-async method which is available since iOS 5.0 but the compiler wrongly (?) selects the new method which is only available since iOS 15.0

Comment: There is also error: `Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled`. Original perform is from `Objective-C` and doesn't have `throws/rethrows`. You just need handle `throws` in the passed block

Comment: @Cy-4AH the original method I want to use does not throw, only the iOS 15 method rethrows.

Comment: @MeXx Then you just need handle all `try`'s

Comment: @Cy-4AH unfortunately no. If I handle it, it still does not compile for iOS < 15 which is what I'm actually trying to do!

Comment: I have just replaced `try` with `try?` and all become fine

Comment: @Cy-4AH wow I've tried this and it works for me as well! I dont understand why, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Cy-4AH I've figured it out!

The problem was, that I was doing everything, including the `context.perform` in one big `do / catch` block

```
do {
    ...
    context.perform({
      let results = try context.fetch(request)
    })
    ...
} catch { 
    ...
}
```

The new extension method for `perform` is now marked as `rethrows` whereas the old one was not, so the fact there was a throwing method in the perform block meant the compiler selected the rethrowing `perform` which is only available on iOS >= 15.

@Cy-4AH suggested to use `try?` instead of `try` which works because the error is caught right there, not forcing the `rethrowing` method to be used.

Another solution is to move the `do/catch` inside the `perform`:

```
context.perform({
  do {
    let results = try context.fetch(request)
  } catch { 
    ...
  }
})
```